# Sitecore 8.1 initial to 8.2 Update 3 Glass Mapper 4.3 looking for IsPageEditor

Tags: sitecore-client, glass-mapper

I am attempting an update from Sitecore 8.1 Initial to 8.2 Update 3 and after running the update package and showing normal warnings on the update, I am getting the below error.

I have already updated my version of GlassMapper so I am running version v4.3.4.197 Not quite sure what is going on. I am using 4.6.2 .Net Framework also.

Using dotPeek I see that GlassMapper 4.3.4.197 does not have IsExperienceEditor which is the only choice in Sitecore 8.2 Update 3.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Method not found: 'Boolean PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Boolean PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean
>   PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()'.]
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Utilities.get_IsPageEditor() in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\Utilities.cs:54
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.Initiate(IDependencyResolver resolver)
>   in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:111
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.IoC.SitecoreContextFactory.GetSitecoreContext(Context
>   context) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\IoC\SitecoreContextFactory.cs:63
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView.Process(GetModelArgs
>   args) in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc\Pipelines\Response\GetModelFromView.cs:91
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +196
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
>
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetModel() +281
>
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Model() +30
>
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ValueOrDefault(T source,
>   Func`2 resultGetter) +57
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.get_Model() +150
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +255
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/Views/MainLayout.cshtml'. ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +148
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +196
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +302
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +375    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +37
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1637.0

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I have already update the GlassMapper

Comment: I have re-opened the question and provided an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jim - so, I think the problem is the same - you are running with a Glass binary that has been compiled against a version of Sitecore where `IsPageEditor` was still available.

When you install the Glass nuget package, it runs a PowerShell script that tries to detect which version of Sitecore you have installed and then references the matching Glass binaries. My guess is that your project may have still referenced the previous version of Sitecore *or* when you upgraded the Glass nuget package, it didn't re-check your `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` version.

If you look in your packages folder, you should see all the versions listed like this:
[image: Glass Nuget Versions]

Check in your project the path to the Glass.Mapper.Sc binary - it should be referencing the one in the `100` folder to match 8.2 update 3, like this:
[image: Glass.Mapper.Sc reference]

If it is not, just delete the reference and re-add it pointing at the right version, or remove it via NuGet and re-add the NuGet reference, if you do that, make sure that your project is referencing the correct version of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll`

Comment: Yes, I did try deleting the reference and re-added it so it look like the correct version. However To go a step further I used the object browser to look at the DLL and it does not show IsExperienceEditor instead the 4.3 dll shows IsPageEditor.

Comment: Did you make sure it was using the dll from the 100 folder? That one will have IsExperienceEditor in it.

Comment: Yes, in fact I uninstalled the nuget packages and reinstalled them. Now my error has changed. I think that I have gotten past this error at this time. Thanks for your help.